# Chrome Extension - Entering in FullScreen Mode turns the page background color to black

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, fullscreen

I am creating a Chrome Extension that allows the user to view any web page in full screen:

> manifest.json

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "...",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "...",
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["jf.js"]
   },
   "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "..."
   },
   "author": "..." ,
   "file_system_provider_capabilities":
  {
    "configurable": false
  },
   "incognito": "spanning",
   "offline_enabled": true,
   "permissions": [
     "tabs",
     "activeTab"
   ],
   "short_name": "..."
}
```

> jf.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {file: "jf.css"});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen()'
 });
});
```

> jf.css

```
body:-webkit-full-screen {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

It works fine but when a page goes into FullScreen Mode through the extension the background color of that same page becomes black, how can I solve that?

I used the FullScreen API described in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API in order to do this extension.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be just a bug from Google. You could try setting the background color of  to the color it was before afterwards.

Comment: I thought about that and I even wrote the code but it doesn’t work so I think that this is a bug like you said. But I found the solution I needed to switch the ‘document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen()’ to ‘document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen()’ and now it works.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. The background in fullscreen mode in Chrome is probably black on purpose. So if you fullscreen the body Chrome turns it black. I'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution I needed to switch the ‘document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen()’ to ‘document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen()’ and now it works.

Thank you!